# Perl DBI connection works but not with Catalyst

Tags: perl, dbi, catalyst, postgresql-9.3

I am using Perl, and I am able to connect to a local PostgreSQL 9.3 server using 
this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use strict;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=postgres;host=127.0.0.1;port=5432", "postgres", "postgres", { RaiseError => 1 }) or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->disconnect();
print "Done\n";
```

Now, following the [Catalyst documentation about PostgreSQL](http://search.cpan.org/~zarquon/Catalyst-Manual-5.8005/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/10_Appendices.pod#PostgreSQL) I try to generate a Catalyst model.

I use this shell command

```
script/myapp_create.pl model DB DBIC::Schema MyApp::Schema \
create=static components=TimeStamp,EncodedColumn \
'dbi:Pg:dbname=postgres,host=127.0.0.1,port=5432' 'postgres' 'postgres' '{ AutoCommit => 1 }'
```

But I get the following error:

```
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::catch {...} (): 
DBI Connection failed: 
DBI connect('dbname=postgres,host=127.0.0.1,port=5432','postgres',...) failed: 
FATAL:  database "postgres,host=127.0.0.1,port=5432" does not exist at 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm line 1487. at 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Catalyst/Helper/Model/DBIC/Schema.pm line 637
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first DBI connection test has a properly configured connection string using semi-colons ';' - your second one is using commas ',' - which are not valid property separators.

Change from;

```
'dbi:Pg:dbname=postgres,host=127.0.0.1,port=5432'...
```

To;

```
'dbi:Pg:dbname=postgres;host=127.0.0.1;port=5432'...
```

Comment: Oh, you are right and correcting them, the command works. This means, I have to change my glasses. At my age ...